# Completion policy in Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have custom spring reader and writer due to some complex logic, where in the reader class i have to read data from DB and writer write the same into the excel file in the writer.
While implementing this I need to read records in chunks and pass the same to the writer for which I'm using "MyCompletionPloicy" java class which extends SimpleCompletionPolicy and in the constructor I'm passing super(1) but the problem is that its reading only one row and writing the same to the excel sheet and it goes into never ending process(run in a loop reder --> writer --> reader --> and so on).
Can some one let me on the same. Please find the sample code.

Job Config -

```
batch:job id="DailyJob">        
    <batch:step id="DailyJobStep1" next="DailyJobStep2">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="DailyJobCSVFileItemReader" writer="DailyJobCSVFileCustomWriter"
                chunk-completion-policy="MyCompletionPloicy" />
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="DailyJobListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

Reader class -

```
public class DailyJobCSVFileItemReader implements
               ItemReader<CSVFileDailyJobBean> {
@Override
public CSVFileDailyJobBean read() throws Exception,
        UnexpectedInputException, ParseException,
        NonTransientResourceException { 
    CSVFileDailyJobBean csvFileDailyJobBean = new CSVFileDailyJobBean()
    // some logic
    return csvFileDailyJobBean;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

your reader implementation needs to return null, to notify spring batch that it is empty

> The read method defines the most essential contract of the ItemReader;
>   calling it returns one Item or null if no more items are left.

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html

Comment: When I'm using SimpleCompletionPolicy and passing super(1) it giving the same row every time when it returns from writer to reader its getting the same result, its not able to increment the count however when we use spring provided reader and pass commit interval then it increment the value and get the next set of result. So I want to achieve the same using completion policy.

Comment: pls add your custom code for the completionPolicy to the question

Comment: Do you have any example for the custom code in the completion policy.

Comment: i meant, that you include your "I'm using "MyCompletionPloicy" java class which extends SimpleCompletionPolicy" in your question, so we can look into the code